# Focus control in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, focus

The context:
I want to have a ListView that wouldn't receive focus (e.g. won't
highlight row when user touches it). Yet each row widget has it's own
OnClickListener.
Here's what I specify in layout xml:

```
android:choiceMode="none" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

The ListView still behaves exactly the same.
Could someone please explain

1. The interrelation between the three
2. What's the right way to create a ListView that doesn't receive focus?

TIA.

Comment: Hi Quintin. I'm having the same problem. Have you found the answer?

Comment: two best solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098558/listview-with-clickable-editable-widget/27898369#27898369

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list receiving focus is different than the selected row not highlighting.  The list gets focus whenever a user is in it.  The best a ListView can do is report an `int` for whatever the user has selected.  I'm not sure how each row widget has it's own ClickListener.  There are no row widgets that I am aware of.  The `onListItemClick` belongs to the ListView.

I havent been able to figure it out yet, but between `android:listSelector` and `android:background` and adjusting the alpha channels I figure there would be a way to make a selection look just like a non-selected row.

`android:listSelector="#8fff"` makes it so just the foreground changes on selection.

It seems like android chooses the non-selected foreground on its own, which is making this hard.  I hope this helps.

Comment: In fact, when you set those attibutes to "@android:color/transparent", there is no visual indication whether the element is being selected or not.

Answer (score 6):

Although you specified in the xml you could try specifying in code as well.  Although i'm not sure you can set a list to not focusable and still have the list be scrollable and it's clickable.

after your setContentView...

```
myListView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
```

You could try and inherit from the view as well and then add a little debugging code in the interim to help you find when the list actually has focus.

```
    myListView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
        {
            v.setBackgroundColor(hasFocus ? Color.GRAY : Color.BLACK);
        }
    });

    myListView.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: I don't understand why but setting `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` in the view XML wouldn't stop it focusing/scrolling at runtime. Only calling `listView.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);` in code worked. Magic!

Answer (score 0):

Cant you do with a RadioButton thats selected when user touches a Row on the List?

Following is a excerpt from my own code.

```
// Create an adapter with a simple list item with single choice.
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, categories);

// Set the adapter to your list
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Cheers!