# ListView with clickable/editable widget

Tags: android, android-widget

Is it possible to use a OnItemClickListener on a ListView when the Items layout has a clickable/editable widget (RadioButton,EditText, or CheckBox)?

Comment: Extends ListActivity instead of Activity . refer http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414). Having a focusable item in a row of a `ListView` causes the `OnItemClickListener` NOT to be invoked. However, that does not mean you cannot have focusable/clickable items in a row, there are some workarounds like [this one](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414#c27).

Also, you can take a look at the Call Logs screen. It has a `ListView` with clickable item(the call icon on the right).
[See Source code here](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/blob/donut-release/src/com/android/contacts/RecentCallsListActivity.java#L380)

Comment: Quick help: "An easy way to work around this problem is to call 
"setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);" 
on the listView views as they are added.
You'll be able to select rows, click on rows and click on child checkboxes and buttons." - This is a quote from comment #27 in the page referred to by two of the links in the answer above. Thanks so much!!

Comment: only the first link is working the others are broken please fixed that

Comment: In addition, make sure not to do things like `android:clickable="true"` in the list row. That was my problem.

Answer (score 21):

Quoting comment #31 in the link mentioned by Samuh (which solved the problem for me):

> In fact you can add it to the layout XML (if inflated by one): android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants".

Adding here JIC that webpage is down in the future.

Answer (score 12):

If any row item of list contains focusable or clickable view then `OnItemClickListener` won't work.

row item must be having param like `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    // your other widgets here

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Tried many complex solutions, but this was the simplest one that worked:

Just use `android:focusable="false"` as in:

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/fav_check_box"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

Comment: This technique is explained in more detail here: http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2010/02/expandable-lists-and-check-boxes.html

Answer (score 0):

Two best solution

1. Add `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"` to listView
   in xml **OR**
2. Set given two attributes to `false`

like

```
   android:focusable="false"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

**Then it will handle the listView row item child(Button,EditText etc) events instead of listView.setOnItemClick .**

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem different , in my item I have more than one LinearLayout
so if you give id to your linearayout and setOnclickListener in adapter class it will work, only original effect of touching will dissapear.
but this link [Making a LinearLayout act like an Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5546514/making-a-linearlayout-act-like-an-button)  is usefull to make linearlaout act like button on click

item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_item_followers_name"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center|start"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Ali"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_item_followers_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/puan_icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_item_followers_mark"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:background="@color/red_400"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="25.5"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt_item_followers_name"
        android:background="@color/red_400"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_item_followers_2b_follow"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/follow_buton" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

inside getView method

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                        ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.deneme, null);

        final Followers2 myObj = myList.get(position);
        LinearLayout linear_one = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_one); // HERE WE DOMUNİCATE IT
        linear_one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(parentActivity, "One Two", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_followers_name);
        TextView mark = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_item_followers_mark);
        final ImageView btn_follow = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_item_followers_2b_follow);
        name.setText(myObj.getName());
        mark.setText(myObj.getScore());
       /* if (myObj.isFollow() == true) {
            btn_follow.setImageResource(R.drawable.following_buton);
        } else {
            btn_follow.setImageResource(R.drawable.follow_buton);
        }

        btn_follow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Followers2 myObj = myList.get(position);
                if (myObj.isFollow() == true) {
                    btn_follow.setImageResource(R.drawable.following_buton);
                } else {
                    btn_follow.setImageResource(R.drawable.follow_buton);
                }
            }
        });*/

        return view;
    }
```