# Not Getting OnItemClick Event of ListView

Tags: android, listviewitem

I'm using one custom listview . When I'm click on listview I didn't getting onClick Event .

Here is my code .

```
        lvlList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvlList);
        lvlList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,int position, long id) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

lvlList.setAdapter(new OrderAdapter(getBaseContext()));
```

### OrderAdapter

```
private class OrderAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public OrderAdapter(Context context) 
    {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.example, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtTest = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTest);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtTest.setText(Util.SampleTest.get(position));
                    return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder 
    {
        public TextView txtTets;
    }

    public int getCount(){return Util.SampleTest.size();}

    public Object getItem(int position){return position;}

    public long getItemId(int position){return position;}
}
```

Comment: Are there any items in the list. You are setting onItemClick. Can you post the code for OrderAdapter.

Comment: yes there are more than 20 items in list . Here i add my OrderAdapter .

Comment: list is display in listview..?

Comment: yes it is display in listview .

Comment: getItem should return Util.SampleTest.get(position) but I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: If that answer of mine solved your problem,mark it as an answer please.

Answer (score 19):

You need to set
`android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` in your custom xml layout file for the LinearLayout or whatever layout you've been using. (for defining your custom row)

You can also refer to [the comments here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414#c27).

Answer (score 5):

If you have clickable items in your list, you have to play with the focus to be able to receive both list item clicked event AND list items children click events.

Call the following code on your list items as they are created:

```
listItem.setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
```

Found on http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414, answer #27

Answer (score 3):

check this: [ListView with clickable/editable widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098558/listview-with-clickable-editable-widget/2098866#2098866)

Comment: i m already having this code . but i dont like to do that way .

Comment: then you apparently won't have onclickitemlistener working :) focusable objects seem to bind onclick events and are placed over the list item. sounds quite reasonable

Answer (score 0):

First, Set Adapter and then set on click listener event on listview. Then try again.

Comment: if not than .. @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     
 }  this function writes out of create method and implements OnClickListener in your activity

Comment: you are using xml for list view controls...?

Comment: check clickable property is disable or editable property is set of any control of listview...

Comment: i checked it . i m not declaring any property like this .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your custom layout does not have a `CheckBox` before the would-be `TextView`. You can use an `ImageView` to fulfill the `CheckBox` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
  if (convertView == null) 
    {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.example, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.txtTest = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTest);
        convertView.setClickable(true);
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
         }
       }

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } 
    else 
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtTest.setText(Util.SampleTest.get(position));
                return convertView;
}
```