# NativeScript: ListView with chart:RadPieChart does not trigger tap-Event on Android

Tags: android, listview, nativescript

I've got the following ListView-Component in NativeScript 7.0:

```
<ListView id="listview" class="list-group" selectionBehavior="Press" itemTap="exercise" row="1" items="{{ listItems }}">
        <ListView.itemTemplate  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
        <GridLayout class="list-group-item" rows="auto, auto" columns="auto, auto" horizontalAlignment="left">
            <Label text="{{ itemName }}" class="list-group-item-heading" width="270" row="0" col="0" style="font-weight: bold;"/>

            <StackLayout row="0" col="1" horizontalAlignment="left" orientation="horizontal">
                <chart:RadPieChart allowAnimation="true" width="50" height="50" seriesSelectionMode="None" pointSelectionMode="None" loaded="pieLoaded" android:focusable="false">
                    <chart:RadPieChart.series selectionMode="None" android:focusable="false">
                        <chart:DonutSeries
                                selectionMode="None"
                                expandRadius="1.0"
                                outerRadiusFactor="1.0"
                                innerRadiusFactor="0.4"
                                valueProperty="Value"
                                items="{{ items }}"
                                android:focusable="false">
                        </chart:DonutSeries>
                    </chart:RadPieChart.series>
                </chart:RadPieChart>
                <Label text="{{ items[0].Value + '%' }}" class="list-group-item-heading" width="50"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </ListView.itemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

On iOS everything works as expected, but on Android the itemTap-Event `exercise()` ist not fired. I think, it is a similar problem like [Android : ListView with Buttons -> OnItemClick do nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275183/android-listview-with-buttons-onitemclick-do-nothing)  but I can't fix it with the piechart. If I delete the `<chart:RadPieChart>`-Section, everything works.

Do you have any idea?

Best regards,
Benno

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the native ListView with RadListView - this works with Android as well, but left a blank page on iOS... I fixt it to deploy on Android a RadListView and on iOS a basic ListView...