# ListView onClickListener() does not work after adding RadioButton

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I have a `ListView` (**my_list.xml**):

```
 <ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
      />
```

The layout for each list item is (**list_item.xml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >

    <ImageView 
          android:id = "@+id/my_icon" 
          android:layout_width ="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height ="wrap_content"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"  
     /> 
    <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/my_str" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height = "wrap_content" 
         android:layout_toRightOf="@id/my_icon"
     /> 

     <!--This radio button makes the list item unselectable, why?-->
     <RadioButton 
         android:id="@+id/my_radio_btn"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
         />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In Java code, I use `SimpleAdapter` for the list:

```
my_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, getOptions(),
           R.layout.list_item, 
           new String[] { "icon1","str1" }, 
           new int[] {R.id.my_icon, R.id.my_str });

my_list.setAdapter(adapter);

//onClickListener does not work after I added RadioButton in list item layout
my_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Log.v("SELECTED", position+""); 
        }
    });
```

As you see, in above code, in the list item layout, I added a `RadioButton`, after I added this button, my list `onClickListener` does not work anymore, why?? (It works if it's without `RadioButton` on list item layout)

Comment: because now its a conflict of gaining **Focus** between your listview's item and the radio button inside that item

Comment: Then how to get rid of this problem? I need radio button on list item, and I need the radio button be selected when user click on item area.

Comment: the click listener only works if no other view is focusable. Setting your CheckBox to focusable="false" should do the trick for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121192/android-custom-listview-unable-to-click-on-items

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Set the following properties to your **RadioButton**:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

and in your *OnItemClickListener*, you need to set the radio button's **checked** flag by code.

---

Set you ListView as below:

```
<ListView
  android:id="@+id/my_list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: Yes, now, it is ok. But how to make the radio button be selected when user click on item area?  (and make it a single selection list)

Comment: see my updated answer... actually you need to handle this by code in your OnItemClickListener to check the radio button when the item is clicked

Comment: Yes, could you also suggest how to make the radio buttons on the list to be a single selection ? I mean, currently, though I set the select mode of the list to be single. but whenever I click on a list item, the radio button is set to "checked" by code, which makes the list looks like multiple selectable.

Comment: what do you mean, sorry i didn't understand. You want radio button to be checked together when a list item is clicked or want it separate/independent from item click?

Comment: I mean the first one you mentioned in your above comment. Generally, I need a single selection feature with radio button. But currently, since I set the radio button to "checked" flag when user click on one item on the list, if user click another item, the other one will also be "checked"...which looks like multip selection.

Comment: check my updated answer. To avoid multiple selection, you need to write custom simpleadapter in which you are judging value for radiobutton in its **getView** method

Comment: nice, I had to add android:clickable="false"

Answer (score 2):

add this code to your RadioButton XML code:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Another keyword to solve this problem is TouchDelegate.

Edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5528945/1285331