# OnItemClickListener not working for List view with different custom layout items

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view with diffent layouts for each row. One row has checkbox along with textview. I have problem with this row. Whenever I click on this row onItemClick listener is not called. The selector to change background color is also not working.

Can someone please suggest how this can be resolved.

Comment: Could we see your XML and Java code please.

Comment: You speak well but we need your relevant code, please

Comment: Try to remove the Checkbox and check if `your problem persists`.

Comment: sorry, my fault... resolved the issue. i need to set the focus to false to check box otherwise it gets the focus and list item won't work as desired... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885803/listview-onclicklistener-does-not-work-after-adding-radiobutton