# Android setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-listview

I'm not able to initiate the "**OnItemClickListener**".

You can see my code snippet

```
 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.main, new String[] { "title"}, new int[] { R.id.item_title});
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    final ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
            Toast.makeText(TopNewsActivity.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

        }
    });
```

after the setListAdapter my debugger goes to "**lv.setOnItemClickListener**" but then does not get into the loop and moves out.

I want to make the links Clickable kindly help.

Comment: I don't see a loop there

Comment: I'm just wondering what you mean by 'get into the loop'?

Comment: @LBNerdBard : Sorry by loop i meant the function. The function is skipped

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to write @Override before public void onItemClick?

```
Adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
        }
});
```

Comment: This can not be the reason, method is overridden whether or not there is an @Override annotation.

Answer (score 8):

The most probable cause is that your ListView items contain either focusable or clickable Views. If a view contains either focusable or clickable item the OnItemCLickListener won't be called. (Instead the clickable View's own click handlers will be called).

Click here for more information.
See my previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview-android/5587975#5587975) or find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098558/listview-with-clickable-editable-widget).

Try it with a very simple ListItem layout - it should work.

Answer (score 0):

bbalazs is right. I would like to put it more precisely: If you have a view A as a child of a view B and A is by default clickable(button f.e.), than setOnItemClickListener won't work on B.
It is pure magic, but it works so.