# how to identify and remove the position ListView

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I extends ArrayAdapter, painted the following picture
[image]

```
public class UrlArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UrlItem> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    public UrlArrayAdapter(Context context, List<UrlItem> urlLists) {
        super(context, R.layout.database_table_list, R.id.editLinearLayout1,urlLists);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        UrlItem urlItem = (UrlItem) this.getItem(position);
        CheckBox checkBox = null;
        TextView textView = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.database_table_item, null);
            textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            convertView.setTag(urlItem);
            checkBox.setChecked(urlItem.getUse());
            textView.setText(urlItem.getUrl());
            textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                }
            });
        } else {
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**how to identify and remove the position  to which I press?**
setOnClickListener() - does not work - account for a long time to click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, in your `getView` method, your code seems incorrect: you need to set values regardless of whether you use converted view or not.  The code should be like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    UrlItem urlItem = (UrlItem) this.getItem(position);
    CheckBox checkBox = null;
    TextView textView = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.database_table_item, null);
    }

    textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    convertView.setTag(urlItem);
    checkBox.setChecked(urlItem.getUse());
    textView.setText(urlItem.getUrl());
}
```

Then, to detect clicks on individual items, do not use `onClickListener` on the items.  Instead, use `setOnItemClickListener` on your `ListView`.  You will have something like this:

```
final UrlArrayAdapter adapter = new UrlArrayAdapter(this, items);
ListView list = this.findViewById(R.id.my_list);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //deal here with removing the item at position _position_
        //from your adapter, then notify the list view that the data has changed
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: 'list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()   does not respond =((  Wait - try

Comment: What do you mean by "does not respond"?

Comment: @MaxUsanin Just out of curiosity, why are you extending the ArrayAdapter?  What's wrong with using it as is?

Comment: i use SQLLite output the results to the list

Comment: do not want to split hairs but your listener does not catch =(  I can not understand why

Comment: Hm... I wouldn't know why without seeing more of your code.  I use the same code in my app and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I probably do something wrong, thanks I'll look for more examples

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098558/listview-with-clickable-editable-widget/2098866#2098866)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long arg3) {
        // REMOVE DATA FROM YOUR LIST ACCORDING TO POSITION.
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

If you are facing any problem then you can ask.