# setOnItemClickListener not work

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I have a situation similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098558/listview-with-clickable-editable-widget/2098866#2098866)

I use `setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS)` and `setOnItemClickListener`, but they do not work.

Here's my source:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.database_table_list);

    LBD conection = new LBD(this);
    conection.open();
    setting = conection.tblSettings();
    setting.create();

    urlLists = setting.selectRssTable();
    urlListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    uAdapter = new UrlArrayAdapter(DatabaseTable.this, urlListView,
            urlLists);

    urlListView.setAdapter(uAdapter);
    urlListView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);
    urlListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            ((BaseAdapter) uAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

All active ELEMENTS.

[**Helped me to this link**](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/)

Comment: did you try the solutions linked in the answer?