# Custome adapter isnt responding to setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android, android-gridview

Hello i have a custome adapter to a gridview that is not responding to

setOnItemClickListener.

I have looked over this issues and nothing helped:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3414

[ListView with clickable/editable widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098558/listview-with-clickable-editable-widget/2098866#2098866)

http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

[Focusable EditText inside ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679948/focusable-edittext-inside-listview/4901683#4901683)

I test my response at my logcat but i dont get any response when i click on item in my gridview.

This is my adapter code:

```
public class GridCellAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
            private static final String tag = "GridCellAdapter";
            private final Context _context;
            private final List<String> list;
            private static final int DAY_OFFSET = 1;
            private final String[] weekdays = new String[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue",
                    "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
            private final String[] months = { "January", "February", "March",
                    "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                    "October", "November", "December" };
            private final int[] daysOfMonth = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30,
                    31, 30, 31 };
            private final int month, year;
            private int daysInMonth, prevMonthDays;
            private int currentDayOfMonth;
            private int currentWeekDay;
            public String lastDateString;

            // Days in Current Month
            public GridCellAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                    int month, int year) {

                super();
                this._context = context;
                this.list = new ArrayList<String>();
                this.month = month;
                this.year = year;

                //Log.d(tag, "==> Passed in Date FOR Month: " + month + " "
                    //  + "Year: " + year);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
                setCurrentDayOfMonth(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                setCurrentWeekDay(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
                //Log.d(tag, "New Calendar:= " + calendar.getTime().toString());
                //Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfWeek :" + getCurrentWeekDay());
                //Log.d(tag, "CurrentDayOfMonth :" + getCurrentDayOfMonth());

                // Print Month
                printMonth(month, year);

            }



            private String getMonthAsString(int i) {

                return months[i];
            }

            private int getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(int i) {
                return daysOfMonth[i];
            }

             public Object getItem(int position) {
                    return position;
                }

            public int getCount() {
                return list.size();
            }

            /**
             * Prints Month
             * 
             * @param mm
             * @param yy
             */
            private void printMonth(int mm, int yy) {
                //Log.d(tag, "==> printMonth: mm: " + mm + " " + "yy: " + yy);
                // The number of days to leave blank at
                // the start of this month.
                int trailingSpaces = 0;
                int daysInPrevMonth = 0;
                int prevMonth = 0;
                int prevYear = 0;
                int nextMonth = 0;
                int nextYear = 0;

                int currentMonth = mm - 1;

                daysInMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(currentMonth);

                // Gregorian Calendar : MINUS 1, set to FIRST OF MONTH
                GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(yy, currentMonth, 1);

                if (currentMonth == 11) {
                    prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                    daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                    nextMonth = 0;
                    prevYear = yy;
                    nextYear = yy + 1;

                } else if (currentMonth == 0) {
                    prevMonth = 11;
                    prevYear = yy - 1;
                    nextYear = yy;
                    daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);
                    nextMonth = 1;

                } else {
                    prevMonth = currentMonth - 1;
                    nextMonth = currentMonth + 1;
                    nextYear = yy;
                    prevYear = yy;
                    daysInPrevMonth = getNumberOfDaysOfMonth(prevMonth);

                }


                int currentWeekDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
                trailingSpaces = currentWeekDay;


                if (cal.isLeapYear(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)) && mm == 2) {
                    ++daysInMonth;
                }

                // Trailing Month days
                for (int i = 0; i < trailingSpaces; i++) {

                    list.add(String
                            .valueOf((daysInPrevMonth - trailingSpaces + DAY_OFFSET)
                                    + i)
                            + "-GREY"
                            + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(prevMonth)
                            + "-"
                            + prevYear);
                }

                // Current Month Days
                for (int i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {

                    if (i == getCurrentDayOfMonth()) {
                        list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-BLUE" + "-"
                                + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                    } else {
                        list.add(String.valueOf(i) + "-WHITE" + "-"
                                + getMonthAsString(currentMonth) + "-" + yy);
                    }
                }

                // Leading Month days
                for (int i = 0; i < list.size() % 7; i++) {

                    list.add(String.valueOf(i + 1) + "-GREY" + "-"
                            + getMonthAsString(nextMonth) + "-" + nextYear);
                }
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                View row = convertView;
                TextView gridcell = null;

                if (row == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context
                            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_day_gridcell, parent,
                            false);
                }

                Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE))
                        .getDefaultDisplay();

                int height = 0;

                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 13) {
                    Point size = new Point();
                    display.getSize(size);
                    height = size.y;

                } else
                    height = display.getHeight();

                float scaledDensity = getApplicationContext().getResources()
                        .getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;

                height = (height / ((int) scaledDensity));

                if (calendarView.getCount() > 35)
                    height = (height - 300) / 7;
                else
                    height = (height - 300) / 6;

                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, height);

                // Get a reference to the Day gridcell
                gridcell = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.calendar_day_gridcell);
                gridcell.setLayoutParams(lp);


                //setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

                String[] day_color = list.get(position).split("-");
                String theday = day_color[0];
                String themonth = day_color[2];
                String theyear = day_color[3];

                // Set the Day GridCell
                gridcell.setText(theday);
                gridcell.setTag(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear);

                if(dateWanted.equals(theday + "-" + themonth + "-" + theyear))
                    gridcell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.LightGreen));

                if (day_color[1].equals("GREY")) {
                    gridcell.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                }
                if (day_color[1].equals("WHITE")) {
                    gridcell.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                }
                if (day_color[1].equals("BLUE")) {
                    gridcell.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(
                            R.color.static_text_color));
                }

                return row;
            }
}
```

The code in my onCreate:

```
calendarView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.calendar);


        adapter = new GridCellAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                R.id.calendar_day_gridcell, month, year);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        calendarView.setAdapter(adapter);

        calendarView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

The lisetner:

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("position", arg2+"");
        }
```

My XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
        android:text="From which date to start"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="17sp" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="65sp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/nextMonth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:src="@drawable/go_next" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/prevMonth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:src="@drawable/go_back" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textMonth"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35sp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:background="@color/LightBlue"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Thu"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Sat"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Sun"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="23dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Fri"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="31sp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Mon"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Tue"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Wed"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"   
         android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:numColumns="7"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to use `onItemSelectedListener` instead of `OnItemClickListener` and try to print in logcat

Comment: show us your xml file: R.layout.calendar_day_gridcell

Comment: use this android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" in root layout of your R.layout.calendar_day_gridcell

Comment: @kettu i changed my view from button to textview and added the line you wrote