# Android: onItemCheckedStateChanged is called only once

Tags: java, android, android-menu

Fragment class:

```
public class MultiFragmentListContent extends ListFragment
{
ListView listView;
ActionMode actionMode;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
List<String> stringList;
Set<String> checkList;
AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener choiceModeListener = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    checkList = new HashSet<>();
    stringList = new LinkedList<>();
    stringList.add("A");
    stringList.add("B");
    stringList.add("C");
    stringList.add("D");
    stringList.add("E");
    listView = getListView();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.string,stringList);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    choiceModeListener = new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked)
        {
            if(checked)
                checkList.add(stringList.get(position));
            else
                checkList.remove(stringList.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
        {
            actionMode = mode;
            MenuInflater menuInflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.contentmenu2,menu);
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.checkbox,stringList);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item)
        {
            switch(item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.contextmenu2:
                    for(String k : checkList)
                    {
                        stringList.remove(k);
                        Log.i(k,k);
                    }
                    actionMode.finish();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
        {
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.string,stringList);
            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            checkList.removeAll(checkList);
        }
    };

    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(choiceModeListener);

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(choiceModeListener);
            return true;
        }
    });

}
}
```

I noted that the method `onItemCheckedStateChanged` is called only once.

Before that method worked, I mean it was always called.

I tried to find on the web but I didn't find a solution.

I think that the problem is

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
```

but I don't know where to put it. If I put it in other places, the app crashes.

Comment: You can add adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after setChoiceMode() and have a try.

Comment: @Paul it doesn't work

Comment: I've tried as your code, but it works fine. And in the choice mode, the function onItemCheckedStateChanged() always been called. I still don't know where the problem is. If you choice nothing in the choice mode, it will exit choice mode. Did you always choice the same item?

Comment: @Paul why does it work for you!? I choose (select) different items of course. Now I'll post all the class. Tell me if it works for you

Comment: Which android version did you use with compiling?

Comment: @Paul the last.

Comment: @Paul Note: R.layout.checkbox is a list of checkboxes

Comment: Oh, I think you should not use checkbox there. It intercepts the click event so that function onItemCheckedStateChanged() would not be called. I tried with it and if I use TextView, it works well.

Comment: @Paul but I need to use checkboxes

Comment: @Paul oh yes, without checkboxes it works, but I need to use them

Comment: @Paul how can I do this?

Comment: if I write `getActivity().findViewById(R.id.checkBox).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                
            }
        });`   the app crashes because the checkbox is a model of the listview, not a true checkbox. Do you understand me?

Comment: Set your checkbox in xml attributes focusable,focusableInTouchMode and clickable with false and have a try. It should let checkbox do not intercept the click event.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this issue.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098558/listview-with-clickable-editable-widget/)

Comment: @Paul OH YES PAUL!! It works! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad it could help.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible if you create one boolean value for your control in onItemCheckedStateChanged, the call always called, but will a have control.

Comment: I didn't understand