# android: List View get selected item method

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view that get data from server and list them into the listview.
by clicking on which items a dialog alert show to user 
my code works fine in api level 26 , but when i run my project in devices with api level 24 , the listener not work and nothing happen..

my listener is in a fragment and the code is like this :

```
public class bedehKariHa extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bedehkariha, container, false);

        set_bedehkariha_list(v);
        return v;
    }

    public void set_bedehkariha_list(View v) {
        new JSONDownloader("http://famila1.ir/khabgah/get_khabgah_cash.php?member_id="+MainActivity.LogedInMemberID, new JSONDownloader.OnLoadCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onDone(final String jDownloderData) {
                final List<HashMap<String, Object>> data;
                cashParser cashparse = new cashParser();
                data = cashparse.bedehkariHaparse(jDownloderData);
                String[] from = {"dong","hazine", "tozihat", "hazine_shareTo0", "hazine_shareTo1", "hazine_shareTo2", "hazine_shareTo3", "hazine_shareTo4", "hazine_shareTo5", "who_paid0", "who_paid1", "who_paid2", "who_paid3", "who_paid4", "who_paid5", "date"};
                int[] to = {R.id.bedehkariha_dong,R.id.mablaq_hazine, R.id.babate_hazine, R.id.moshtarak_ba1, R.id.moshtarak_ba2, R.id.moshtarak_ba3, R.id.moshtarak_ba4, R.id.moshtarak_ba5, R.id.moshtarak_ba6, R.id.pardakhtaz1, R.id.pardakhtaz2, R.id.pardakhtaz3, R.id.pardakhtaz4, R.id.pardakhtaz5, R.id.pardakhtaz6, R.id.tarikh_hazine};
                SimpleAdapter myadapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        getView().getContext(), data, R.layout.bedehkariha_row, from, to
                );
                final ListView lv = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list_bedehkariha);

                lv.setAdapter(myadapter);



                lv.setOnItemClickListener(

                        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                                Toast.makeText(null, "you are in on item click method", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                final HashMap<String,Object> test = data.get(i);
                                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getView().getContext());
                                alert
                                        .setCancelable(false)
                                        .setMessage("آیا از تسویه این بدهی اطمینان دارید؟"+"\n"+"مبلغ کل: "+ test.get("hazine") +"\n"+"بابت:"+ test.get("tozihat") + "\n"+"تاریخ:" + test.get("date") )
                                        .setTitle("هشدار")
                                        .setPositiveButton("بله مطمئنم",
                                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                                        String URL = "http://famila1.ir/khabgah/set_data.php?cashID="+test.get("id")+"&memberID="+test.get("member_id")+"&whoPaidID="+MainActivity.LogedInMemberID;
                                                        new JSONDownloader(URL, new JSONDownloader.OnLoadCallback() {
                                                            @Override
                                                            public void onDone(final String s) {
                                                                AlertDialog.Builder alret = new AlertDialog.Builder(getView().getContext());
                                                                alret.setTitle("توجه!");
                                                                if (s.contains("done")){
                                                                    alret.setMessage("درخواست تسویه حساب شما با موفقیت ثبت گردید و پس از تایید از مامان خرج درج می گردد");

                                                                }else{
                                                                    alret.setMessage("درخواست ثبت تسویه حساب شما با خطا مواجه شد، لطفا بعدا مجددا تلاش فرمایید");

                                                                }
                                                                alret.create().show();
                                                            }
                                                        }).execute();

                                                    }
                                                })
                                        .setNegativeButton("لفو", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                                Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), "در خواست شما لغو گردید", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        });
                                alert.create().show();
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        }).execute();

    }
}
```

problem is in this line in api level 24 is not going in this function:

```
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(

                        new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
```

Comment: Does your list item layout contain clickable or focusable views? See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098558/listview-with-clickable-editable-widget

Comment: I suggest that you try to isolate the `setOnItemClickListener` code and try to just test it (and use `Log.e()` instead if `Toast`). I have the an app with `setOnItemClickListener` working fine in a device with Android version 6.0.1 (API 23)

Comment: @BadCash i try that , nothing change

Comment: @Barns nothing change , the program does not go into setOnItemClickListener method in api 23 , and i dont know why this is accure to my app