# Android: Highlighting list items in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an application that has a listview and I would like to highlight a particular list item when the user is on that activity.

So far I have a general implementation where I am creating a listView and I have an OnListItemClick method. I would appreciate it if someone could provide a sample implementation of how to highlight a particular listitem in a listview.

Comment: Let me know if this post helps you a bit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572053/focus-control-in-a-listview

Answer (score 0):

It should be done automatically, but otherwise you can do what I wrote here: [How can I highlight the table row on click ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075356/how-can-i-highlight-the-table-row-on-click/8204768#8204768)

Set the background of the view you are inflating in your [Adapter.getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method to `android:background="@android:drawable/list_selector_background"`...

Comment: I dont want to highlight it on clicking it. I would like to highlight the 2nd list item in my listview whenever I go to that screen.

Comment: ahh than in your adapter do the following:
`if(position == 1 || item.equals(itemToHighlight)) //not sure if you want to do it by position or the item itself, its up to you, remove one or the other
{
convertView.setBackground(R.color.highlight_color); 
{ else {
convertView.setBackground(android.R.color.transparent);
}`